# Displaying Info from loop on specific section of page

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

so stack say's I'm horrible at asking questions which i'm terribly sorry about, So i'll try be as clear as possible :). I'm trying to take information from the user:

```
<input type='text' name="getName" id="userinput">
<input type="button" value="go" id='go' onclick="doStuff()">
```

then store the users info in an array and loop through it.

```
window.onload = function doStuff() {


var info = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
var infoArray = [info];


for(i=0; i < infoArray.length; i++){
document.getElementById('#playing').innerHTML = document.write(infoArray[i++]);
```

}
}

I Keep getting a 'Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'
 or if i don't use the inner html and try:

```
for(i=0; i < infoArray.length; i++){
document.write(infoArray[i++]);
```

}

the page refreshes and i cant put it where i want? So I guess my question is how do i take the info from the looped array and display it on a certain part of the page.

Sorry if my codes awful, only ever really dabbled before. Thanks for taking the time and hope this made a little sense

Comment: Do you just need to add css?

Comment: 1. Increasing `i` twice in one iteration 2. `document.getElementById('#playing').innerHTML = document.write(infoArray[i++]);` ???

Comment: Maybe just add css to userInput. Position : absolute

Comment: oh sorry that was a mistake.

Comment: window.onload = function doStuff() is attaching "doStuff" it to the load. onclick="doStuff()" is attaching "doStuff" to a button click". What do you want? click or onload? document.getElementById('#playing') is (obviously) not finding the element. hence a {null}.innerHTML is causing you pain. Check your HTML for an element with the ID="playing". Furthermore; .innerHTML = document.write(infoArray[i++]); is weird. Either "assign infoArray[x]" to innerHTML or "document.write" it, not both.

Comment: this is wrong at every step. get rid of document.write not needed there, get rid of window.load not needed rest all good

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to onload and forgot about the dostuff(doh). I have an HTML element I called playing.

Comment: Thank you guys! All that helped and it's working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
document.getElementById('#playing')
```

Where you're including the `#` which is wrong. Do it like this instead:

```
document.getElementById('playing').innerHTML = document.write(infoArray[i++]);
```

Comment: This is how I truly solved it. I don't know how I got it into my head that the # was used.

Comment: @SamuelGreen Then it would appropriate to accept this answer for future reference.